# Cannot insert rows above range?

Tags: excel, vba

i wrote the following code, in order to paste the rngtocopy ABOVE rngins....

Now ive tried around a lot and it keeps adding it below the rngins and i have no idea why.
I tried out xlshiftup, which actually gives me errors, probably cause there are values above?

```
Sub reviewverschieben()

Dim counter As Long, lrow As Long, lrowrev As Long, i As Long, lastrev As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngtocopy As Range, rngins As Range
Dim lastcolumn As String

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False

counter = 0

With ws
lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Do While counter = 0
  For i = 32 To lrow
    If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "Review Participants" And counter = 1 Then
     lrowrev = i

    ElseIf .Cells(i, 1).Value = "Review Participants" And i <> lrow Then
     counter = counter + 1
     lastrev = i  'row nr which we take as a reference to insert new table above
     lrowrev = lastrev
     lcol = .Cells(i + 1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last meeting of the review is our reference for lastcol

        ElseIf counter = 1 And i = lrow Then
        lrowrev = lrow + 2
        Exit For
End If
Next
Loop

lastcolumn = Split(Cells(, lcol).Address, "$")(1)
Set rngtocopy = .Range("A" & 32 & ":" & lastcolumn & lrowrev)

Debug.Print rngtocopy.Address

Set rngins = .Range("A" & 32 & ":" & lastcolumn & lrowrev)
Debug.Print rngins.Address

        'Range("A" & lrow).Offset(5).EntireRow.Hidden = False
             rngtocopy.Copy
             rngins.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
             ringins.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
```

[Image for better clarification, what i have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPsES.png)

Comment: But your code `rngins.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown` "tells" VBA to insert bellow the last row of `rngins` range. Can you explain IN WORDS, what would you like to happen when inserting?

Comment: lets say rngins is A2:K5 and rngtocopy is A2: K3. I want rngtocopy, to be insert ABOVE rngtocopy.

Comment: OK. please see my code answer in order to understand the logic...

Comment: @FaneDuru did you delete your answer?

Comment: Yes, I did that...  It looked useless in the discussion context. I will undelete it if necessary.

Comment: it actually helped me solve my problem :) undelete please, so i can confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to make space for copying of `rngins` range you should proceed as following:

```
Dim aboveR As Long
aboveR = rngins.Cells(1, 1).row
sh.Rows(aboveR & ":" & aboveR + rngtocopy.Rows.Count - 1).Insert xlDown
```

This piece of code will insert above the `rngins` range as many rows as `rngtocopy` range has.

If you need to insert only some rows of the range, the second parameter will need to replace `rngtocopy.Rows.Count` with that specific number of rows. And then, the paste cell  must be determined by adding that number to the existing `aboveR` value:

```
Dim pasteCell As Range
Set pasteCell = sh.Range("A" & aboveR + rngtocopy.Rows.Count)
 rngtocopy.Copy pasteCell
```

And in order to make your code working in the way you wanted, try this:

```
rngtocopy.Copy
rngins.Cells(1, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clear clipboard
```

When you try to insert rows and there is something in clipboard, the clipboard content is inserted...

Comment: first adding the amount of rows, that i copied, solved the problem, although i dont know why it even caused one :) thx!

Comment: @Dimi: I will show you how your code must be modified to insert where you want, on the way you tried... I will take it like a challenge...  Did it. Please check my updated answer (refresh the page first...).

Comment: I haven't tried it out yet but I think the last tip is important... I didn't clear my clipboard and that might have caused me hours of troubleshooting....

Comment: The code should work without the clipboard cleaning. It is just better to clean the clipboard a that point. If you need to only insert rows, you may have a problem... And, if the range size is big, it can be a useless memory overload, too. But `ringins.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll` must be omitted. And use `rngins.Cells(1, 1).Insert`. This sets the insertion point above the range...

Answer (score 0):

Your specification of RngIns may well be described as adventurous, considering this little piece of code juggling: `lastcolumn = Split(Cells(, lcol).Address, "$")(1)`. I recommend that you define the range like this.

```
Set rngIns = .Range(.Cells(32, "A"), .Cells(lrowrev, lcol))
```

The code defines the first and last cells of the range and that makes it easy for you to follow. Now, if you insert **at** rngIns the insertion will be made below that range. If you insert **at** RngIns.Offset(1) the insertion will be made above rngIns. Of course, you can make that same difference by defining rngIns's row differently, perhaps like `Set rngIns = .Range(.Cells(33, "A"), .Cells(lrowrev + 1, lcol))`.

However, I wonder why you insert cells at all. Wouldn't it be easier to insert so many sheet rows and then paste to the blank rows?

Comment: "However, I wonder why you insert cells at all. Wouldn't it be easier to insert so many sheet rows and then paste to the blank rows?"
Well this is actually what i am trying to do. i dont care if i insert whole rows or just my cells. the point is, that they are above the copied range